# spring batch - auto re-run jobs that fail due to deadlock exception

Tags: spring, spring-batch, deadlock

I have created a spring batch application that i have deployed on multiple nodes/servers.  I am using sql server 2008 R2 as the jobs repository.  All of the nodes trigger the same job at the same time, which some times causes a deadlock exception (Stack trace below).  At least one node always runs the job.  Some some nodes fail the job by throwing org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException.  I would like to add retries to the 'job' tag of spring batch configuration so that when a job fails due to deadlock exception, it can be tried once again (which i presume will fail due to JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException).

There is something similar that can be configured at the chunk-level.  Please provide suggestions if there is anything like this at the job level

Stack Trace:

```
2014-12-19 14:12:07,866 ERROR main [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner] - 
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not increment identity; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.java:108)
....
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
....
org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer.java:105)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the talk Gunnar Hillert and I did at SpringOne2GX in 2013.  There Gunnar demonstrated using Spring Integration in combination with Spring Batch to send messages upon step or job failures  that would restart the job.  You can view the talk itself here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tiqeV07XlI

Take a look at 32:58 to be specific.